# vscode, javascript - navgiate to function definition with CTRL + Click

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: navigate to function definition with ctrl + click]

In VsCode, is there any way to navigate to function definition, to `someFunction` in this case, line 10, with `ctrl + click`.

Have already checked navigation docs for VS Code 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved
but the answer is not there.

Comment: Search in the command palette "go to implementation" or "go to definition", to the right of search result you should see a keyboard shortcut hint. I think the default is cmd+down, if I remember it right.

Comment: Already have binding for both of these. `go to definition` returns `no implementation found` and the other `no implementation found`.
But thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: Ah, i see. Try not to write code this way. TS engine is not that powerful to analyse everything. If this is not your code but a lib, then sorry can't help. Static analysis on a dynamic lang isn't easy. I'm not sure how well Webstorm handles it.  Multiple-million business lives on it, doesn't come for free :-/

Comment: press `f12` to go the definition or right click to and select `go to definition`

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Did that. `no definition found`.

Comment: then all you can do it `ctrl + f` to search in the same file or `ctrl + shift + f` to search for the complete source code

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Yes, I could get all the symbols in a few ways including `ctrl + shift + o`. That is working just fine. No problems with that whatsoever. Neither of them actually allows to simply use `ctrl + click` at the function name to navigate to function definition/implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install and enable `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` extension in your VS Code for the JavaScript.

After installing this extension restart your VS Code, and try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> to navigate into the function.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl + click` or `F12` is the way to do this. However it only works if VS Code can properly understand your code, which it cannot do here

The specific bug you is [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18171): `this` does not have a known type inside ES5-style constructor functions. You can check this by hovering over `self` and seeing that its type is `any`.

In general, VS Code will have a more difficult time figuring out old, more dynamic JavaScript while `class` and modern constructs can be better analyzed and understood.